# QXMLStreamReader is skipping over text elements

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I am writing out an XML file with some data. Later I want to read the XML file and use the data in my program. However, when I read it back in, QXMLStreamReader seems to be skipping over some child elements.

Here is a snip from my XML file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEMPROOT>
    <Parent1>
        <C0>238.195|1401.12</C0>
        <C1>795.475|1087.65</C1>
        <C2>995.748|756.766</C2>
    </Parent1>
    <Parent2>
        <left>248</left>
        <right>671</right>
        <Width>496</Width>
        <Height>583</Height>
    </Parent2>
    <Parent3>
        <Number>9</Number>
        <Blue>4</Blue>
        <Red>5</Red>
    </Parent3>
</TEMPROOT>
```

It reads Parent1 and its children correctly. My code recognizes Parent2, but skips over its children and goes directly for Parent3 where it reads its children correctly.

Here is my code where I *WRITE* out the XML:

```
QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("TEMPROOT");

xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Parent1");
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("C0", str0);
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("C1", str1);
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("C2", str2);
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();

xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Parent2");
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("left", QString::number(rectCoord[0]));
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("right", QString::number(rectCoord[1]));
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Width", QString::number(rectCoord[2]));
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Height", QString::number(rectCoord[3]));
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();

xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Parent3");
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Number", strNum);
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Blue", strBlue);
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Red", strRed);
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();

xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
```

Here is how I *READ* in the XML file:

```
QXmlStreamReader xmlReader(&file);
QVector<QString> Qv1;
QVector<double> QV2;
QVector<QString> Qv3;
while (!xmlReader.isEndDocument())
{
    xmlReader.readNext();
    QString Name = xmlReader.name().toString();
    if (Name == "Parent1")
    {
        while (xmlReader.name().toString() != "Parent2")
        {
            if (xmlReader.name().toString().at(0) == "C")
            {
                QV1.append(xmlReader.readElementText());
            }
            xmlReader.readNext();
        }
     }
     else if (Name == "Parent2")
    {
        while (xmlReader.name().toString() != "Parent3")
        {
            if (xmlReader.name().toString() == "left")
            {
                QV2.append(xmlReader.readElementText().toDouble());
            }
            else if (xmlReader.name().toString() == "right")
            {
                QV2.append(xmlReader.readElementText().toDouble());
            }
            else if (xmlReader.name().toString() == "Width")
            {
                QV2.append(xmlReader.readElementText().toDouble());
            }
            else if (xmlReader.name().toString() == "Height")
            {
                QV2.append(xmlReader.readElementText().toDouble());
            }
            xmlReader.readNext();

        }
    }
    else if (Name == "Number")
    {
        Qv3.append(xmlReader.readElementText());
    }
    else if (Name == "Blue")
    {
        Qv3.append(xmlReader.readElementText());
    }
    else if (Name == "Red")
    {
        Qv3.append(xmlReader.readElementText());
    }
}
```

The **MAIN** issue is that the `Name` variable, which is the name of the current XML element on `xmlReader` goes from `Parent2` straight to `Parent3` ignoring the children of `Parent2`. The children of `Parent1` and `Parent3` are being read in with no problems. Am I doing something wrong when I read or write the xml?

Comment: Step through this in your debugger. Does it ever enter the `else if (Name == "Parent2")` code block?

Comment: Yes it does, but it does not hit any of the if/ else if blocks in the while loop. `xmlReader.name().toString()` goes from `Parent2` to `Parent3` skipping over `Parent2` children.

Comment: Without studying things too far, I'm thinking you already eat Parent2 in the Parent1 loop because you have already fetched it with readNext(). Try examining the value of Name each time it is set.